# ABC is a triangle, D is a point in the triangle. E is the midpoint of BD. AB=BC, angle ABD= angle DBC=35 degrees, angle ACD=25 degrees. Angle BAE=?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I tried to solve this problem but couldn't. I just know that here, angle BDC= 100 degrees, angle BAC= 40 degrees, AB^2+AD^2=2(AE^2+BE^2) and AB/AD={sin(angle DAE)}/{sin(angle BAE)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that with this introduction you could solve the problem. Let me know if you have difficulties.

[image]

And solve for $\alpha$